How can I improve the load speed on Iframe embedded videos?
Hello lovely people on stackoverflow.
Am using html and css in Dreamweaver to create a website.
I am sourcing videos from a television archive and embedding them onto my website using iframe. It worked OK before, but recently takes ages to buffer. Is there anything I can do to improve it? Sometimes the buffer speed is unwatchable.
Here is the current HTML and CSS code I am using. The container is to help adapt the site to phones and different screens. Am not much of a programmer, so the way I am working is probably not ideal, but it is functional.
Any suggestions very welcome.
Thanks in advance.
HTML
<td width="100%"><div class="container">
      <iframe class="responsive-iframe"  width="100%" height="100" src="https://www.salto.nl/embed/future-vision-amsterdam/2MNA3nOyWAGOAcImEg8IYQ"transparent=1" scrolling="no" overflow="hidden" allowfullscreen allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"> </iframe>

    </div>

CSS
.container { overflow: hidden; border: 0; position: relative; width: 70%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top: 45%; / 16:9 Aspect Ratio (divide 9 by 16 = 0.5625) / scrolling: no; background-color: none;

}

Then style the iframe to fit in the container div with full height and width / .responsive-iframe { border: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 86%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; scrolling: no;

}

Having all the videos on one page might just be too much and I need to redesign and rethink the structure.
I tried adding loading="lazy" to the iframes, but not sure it did much to improve things. I read about something called an ajax call, but am not a great coder and would need to do more research to learn how to implement it. Any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated.

You've already tried adding loading="lazy" to the iframe, which is a good first step. You can try preloading the iframe.
Refer to How to preload iframes
Having multiple videos on a single page can cause performance overheads, consider reducing the number of videos per page or implementing something like pagination or lazy-loading to load videos as the user scrolls.

Thank you! Really appreciate your helpful advice. Am going to try your suggestions for sure.

Link-only answers are not good answers
